# Is assign with braces the same as call the constructor?

Tags: c++, initialization

I know that for scalar types you can assign values with braces like `int a { 0 };`.

This helps with cast, type conversion ecc.

But what for udt? Is

```cpp
shared_ptr<int> myIntSmartPtr { my_alloc(42), my_free };
```

the same as

```cpp
shared_ptr<int> myIntSmartPtr = shared_ptr<int>(my_alloc(42), my_free);
```

The braces should call the constructor, right?

Is it like an initializer list?

I know what an `std::initializer_list` is, but it must be the same type `T`, while in `{ my_alloc(42), my_free }` the types diverge.

Comment: Note that *there is no assignment* in your code. The `=` in this case isn’t an assignment, it’s a form of initialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [direct list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

```cpp
shared_ptr<int> myIntSmartPtr { my_alloc(42), my_free };
```

This is an example of the first syntax:

```cpp
T object { arg1, arg2, ... };   (1)
```

The exact effect it has is therefore

> List initialization is performed in the following situations:
>
> - direct-list-initialization (both explicit and non-explicit constructors are considered)
>
>   1. initialization of a named variable with a *braced-init-list* (that is, a possibly empty brace-enclosed list of expressions or nested braced-init-lists)

And for more detail about what that actually means:

> The effects of list-initialization of an object of type T are:
>
> ... [A bunch of cases that don't apply]
>
> Otherwise, the constructors of T are considered, in two phases:
>
> - All constructors that take std::initializer_list as the only argument, or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have default values, are examined, and matched by overload resolution against a single argument of type std::initializer_list
> - If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the *braced-init-list*, with the restriction that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed. If this stage produces an explicit constructor as the best match for a copy-list-initialization, compilation fails (note, in simple copy-initialization, explicit constructors are not considered at all).

`std::shared_ptr` does not have a constructor that takes an `std::initializer_list`, so the second bullet point applies and it's constructed from the arguments therein.